# How to divide DataGridView rows into many pieces?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I got a datagridview showing below table.

```
Date                        Value
2020-10-05 13:42:27 ET      1
2020-10-05 13:42:28 ET      3
2020-10-05 13:42:29 ET      4
2020-10-05 13:42:30 ET      6
2020-10-05 13:42:31 ET      7
2020-10-05 13:42:32 ET      8
2020-10-06 13:55:33 ET      8
2020-10-06 13:55:35 ET      10
2020-10-06 13:55:5 ET       55
2020-10-06 13:55:10 ET      55
2020-10-06 13:55:20 ET      22
2020-10-06 13:55:4 ET       44
2020-10-06 13:55:8 ET       43
2020-10-07 ...              ...
```

And, i wanna change this table to into this.It shows only few columns with dates and value summary, when you click on that rows it shows more rows.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7vb.jpg)

Do i have to change my datagridview into other controls? Or have to use visible on rows click event handler?

Comment: If you want to do this in one grid you'll probably need a custom control; datagridview could be abused into doing it but you'd effectively be implementing a custom control anyway. Alternatively you could have a pair of dgv and a related databinding scenario where clicking one dgv filters the other. If you want that, say so and I'll tell you how to set it up

Comment: i want it, can u tell me how to filter and set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a new DataSet to your project:

[image]

- Open it. Right click the surface, add a datatable, call it DateGroups. Add another, called Data. Right click each table and add a column called DateGroup and set the type to be DateTime in the grid on the right. Add more columns to data, to hold your accurate dates and value etc. You should have:

[image]

- Click the grey margin to the left of DateGroup in DateGroups to turn the whole line blue (not just the word DateGroup), then drag the line and drop it onto the DateGroup in Data. The Create Relation dialog appears. Check that DateGroups is the parent, and that the two columns to be related are DateGroup:

[image]

- Now a relation line should be showing. Right click the parent table DateGroup line and choose Set Primary key. A key should show too:

[image]

- Switch to your form designer and go View Menu >> Other windows >> Data sources, to show the data sources panel, which should contain a node representing your dataset. Expand all the nodes. Note that there are two for Data:

[image]

- The top level one (red line) is standalone, the one under DateGroups will auto filter (it's relational:

[image]

- Drag the DateGroups node onto the form. Drag the child (yellow) Data node onto the form:

[image: a]

- Some stuff appears. You can delete the bindingnavigator, but leave the other stuff. There are two datagridview, each bound to a bindingsource. The two bindingsource is where the data relating happens; the child (data) bindingsource binds to the relation of the parent (dategroups) bindingsource. Now we need to add some data to the tables that these bindingsources are connected to.
- Switch to code view, put some stuff in the tables. I do this by parsing the values you posted to show you how it works, but you should do it by the same way your existing data got into your grid:

```
string raw = @"2020-10-05 13:42:27 ET      1
2020-10-05 13:42:28 ET      3
2020-10-05 13:42:29 ET      4
2020-10-05 13:42:30 ET      6
2020-10-05 13:42:31 ET      7
2020-10-05 13:42:32 ET      8
2020-10-06 13:55:33 ET      8
2020-10-06 13:55:35 ET      10
2020-10-06 13:55:5 ET       55
2020-10-06 13:55:10 ET      55
2020-10-06 13:55:20 ET      22
2020-10-06 13:55:4 ET       44
2020-10-06 13:55:8 ET       43";

            foreach (var line in raw.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                var bits = line.Split();
                var d = DateTime.ParseExact(bits[0] + bits[1], "yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:s", null);
                var v = int.Parse(bits.Last());

                var day = d.Date;//cut the time off, this gives our "by days

                //try to find the parent Row for this date
                var parentRow = dataSet1.DateGroups.FindByDateGroup(day);

                //if it's not found, create a new one
                if(parentRow == null)
                    parentRow = dataSet1.DateGroups.AddDateGroupsRow(day); //add the parent so next time it will find

                //add the child row related to this parent
                dataSet1.Data.AddDataRow(parentRow, d, v);
            }

        }
```

- That's it.. Just run the program, click a line in the left grid to filter the right grid into days:

[image]
[image]

- You can get the parent to do things like Sum and Average the child row values. Open the dataset again, add an **integer** column to the parent, called SumChildValues, set its `expression` to `Sum(Child.SomeValue)` - somevalue being the column name of the child table:

[image]

- Switch to the form designer, right click the parent grid, choose Add Column, add a bound column connected to the new Sum column we made. Run the app (i also added the Avg column):

[image]

- The values in the parent will update automatically if you change values in the child table